# Netatalk user in both rwlist and rolist

Tags: permissions, file-sharing

I'm currently configuring a AFP server that's running OD, AFP, SMB etc. My problem is that I got a few shares that ALL needs to have read only on and a few people in a specific group needs to have read write on. It looks like this in afp.conf

```
 [Folder]
    valid users = @folderrw @ALLusers 
    path = /srv/Folder/Folder 
    rwlist = @folderrw
    rolist = @ALLusers
    umask = 0007
    file perm = 0770
    directory perm = 0770
```

The problem is that some users is obviously going to be in the rwlist but ofcourse they will still be in the ALLusers list as well. And when I try to create a test user that's in @ALLusers and also in @folderrw since the user is going to be able to edit as well, the user gets read-only and not readwrite, I've tried to search for this but can not find much.